# is a way to run jsf 2.0 on oc4j 10.1.3.5?

Tags: java, jsf-2, oc4j

i'm trying to run jsf 2.0 on oc4j server 10.1.3.5 but the problem oc4j server support 
servlet 2.4 .
Is a way to let the servet use servlet 2.5 to support jsf 2.0 ???

Comment: Even if there is, shouldn't you be considering upgrading into newer Java EE container? OC4J has been discontinued since Oracle acquired weblogic. Afterall Java EE is designed with write-once deploy anywhere paradigm right?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, no. You have to upgrade your server to some which supports at least Servlet 2.5 (and better 3.0).

Comment: i used the latest version of the server